# Excel 2019: Trying to find the number of times one number appears after a specific other number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have around 15K rows all 20 columns. Each cell is a number. I need to find how often one number appears after another. For example how often 18 is in the cell to the right of 17. But I need to do this over 15K rows for 400+ numbers. Any formulaic ideas? Thought about =concat but the numbers range from 0-9999 so it might mind 1718 and think that is 17 18 after the concat function. Open to anything I have been stuck on this one for awhile.

Comment: I would use `textjoin` with a delimiter that is not in your data set, then you can be sure that you won't have the situation you described 1718 vs 17 18. However, are you searching just by row or do you have to combine all 15K rows X 20 columns? if that second case I would expect textjoin to fail.

Comment: Just by rows. I actually "solved" this by using 19 Count(Filter) combinations to add each column together. In the future text join seems much more reasonable.

Comment: This is a classic case for `COUNTIFS` see my [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1764049/)

Answer (score 0):

As `gns100` says, the standard way of combining cells to avoid the problem you described is to insert a character which one is sure does not exist in the data, nor should be expected to in future data.

The "pipe" symbol is often a convenient one actually on the keyboard. It also is usually distinctive enough in a font that it is mildly useful visually if literally looking at the results. However, any font offers LOTS of good ones, and after selecting one, you can Search for it to see if it does already exist in the data. in this case, as the data is only numbers it or any letter is fine.

So you'd be looking for a string like "17|18" and 171 preceding 8 would be "171|8" so no match.

The second really standard way of doing a search for a piece in a string is to find the length of the string, use `SUBSTITUTE` on it changing what you are looking for into emptiness (`""`), and subtracting the latter from the former. If it equals a value, at least one instance was found. If you want to know how many, you can divide that result by the length of the search string. So if a string is 80 in length and after the substitution/s is 55 in length with a search/substitution string length of 5, then there were 25/5 = 5 instances of the search string.

To do that, BY ROW, you can use a formula like this:

```
=(LEN(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE, B1:U1))  -  LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE, B1:U1), TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE, A1&"|"&(A1+1) ), "")))  /  LEN(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE, A1&"|"&(A1+1) ))
```

and copy it down the column. (Picture the search values for each row in column A, so also copied down the column to match the rows. And the data in B1:U26250.)

Then... well, the whole thing is kind of a bear, and your language suggests you want only pairs that occur IN ROWS, so cells B3 and C3, say, but cells B3 and B4 are not a valid pairing, but that you DO want to search to whole data set, for row pairings anywhere in it (all 26,250 rows in my example). The other way, learning the result for each row on its own, would be possible, but hard enough to describe with its possibilities that I shall not "go there" without something rather more explicit in the question.

So, what of searching "the whole thing"? That's... actually vastly easier. The above calculation was, to the eye, for a 26,250 row table, instantaneous. And so is the following. No breakdowns in the formulas either.

As to breakdown by, say, `TEXTJOIN`, the concern is that Excel only will allow the text in a cell to be 32,767 characters long. And many functions have much shorter limits, some in the 6,000 range, some in the 8,000 arena. Further, some functions only allow parameters to be "so long." (`VLOOKUP` for example. Its lookup parameter will only be considered to 256 characters so if you provide it in the formula as a result from some other bits of formula, you might provide something longer without realizing it is happening...) The list of pitfalls here is long.

What is not realized, usually, is that so long as you do not cause the function itself to exceed its own limits, Excel can use a MASSIVE amount of material in the evaluation of the formula. So use `TEXTJOIN`, say, and keep its maximum output to 6,000 characters so that it doesn't chop off the array it passes to the rest of the formula at some awkward spot, and apply it so the formula is handling 26,250 rows all in the same calculation, and even though the material being handled is 26,250*6,000 = 157,500,000 characters, Excel happily chugs along, using it all. So, like a million and a half times that 32,767 text character limit on formula length.

Even works for simply `Joining` of data too. The following formula looks for pairing for a single one of the 400+ inputs you need to check:

```
=SUM(  ($B$1:$T$26250 & $C$1:$U$26250 = A1 & (A1+1))  *1)
```

Notice the offset in the two ranges it joins. It gets the left of the pairing from the first column to the next to last column, and the right of the pairing from the second column to the last column. It compares those resulting strings (each string far less than Excel's limits for strings, but then a LOT of those not-too-long strings) to the search pairing and generates an internal array of TRUE/FALSE results (another huge piece that would seem to violate limits, but as explained, isn't actually subject to those limits). One could literally count, using `COUNTA`, how many TRUE's are in it, but another very standard thing for Excel users is to coerce Excel to make them 1's and 0's by multiplying that array by 1. Actually, any arithmetic on such an array would work, so two of them added or multiplied would do it themselves, but a single array like this one has to have this bit added to the formula. Then, once the array is all numbers, `SUM` adds them up.

This formula looks to a single cell, A1 here, for what to look up. So you can place your list of 400+ values in a column and copy the formula down next to them to get the results for each of the 400+ values.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get your count(s) is using [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function.

> The [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times all criteria are met.
> `=COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)`

**Choose only 1** of the 3 formulas below:

1. **is the simplest**
2. **builds on #1**
3. **builds on #2**

### Formula (#1)

---

<sup>*The formula below in `D3`could be pasted into `D4:D10` to achieve your goal.*</sup>

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,E3,B:B,F3)
```

[image]

### LAMBDA Formula (#2)

---

<sup>*The basic formula above could be converted using the [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function.  This would allow you to use a **single formula** in `D3` that dynamically adapts to changing rows of **Data** and **Lookup Values***</sup>

> Use a [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function to create custom, reusable functions and call them by a friendly name. The new function is available throughout the workbook and called like native Excel functions.
> `=LAMBDA([parameter1, parameter2, …,] calculation)`

###### Step 1 of 2

<sup>*Converts your basic formula above into an equivalent [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) formula.*</sup>

```
1   =LAMBDA(_col1, _col2,
2           COUNTIFS( _col1, E3, _col2, F3 )
3    )( A:A, B:B )
4
5    #  Line numbers in this [code block] are only to 
6    #  allow me to refer to portions of the code below.
```

- Line 1: Two **names** are defined for the two **values** being passed into the [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function function. It's required that `COUNT(names)=COUNT(values)`
- Line 3: Two **values** are defined to pass into the [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function.  In this case they are both ranges.
- Line 2: The formula that replaces the original basic formula.

```
# Original formula compared to Line of LAMBDA based formula

  Original:  COUNTIFS(  A:A, E3,   B:B, F3)
  Line 2:    COUNTIFS(_col1, E3, _col2, F3)
```

[image]

###### Step 2 of 2

<sup>*Now complete the formula by removing the hardcoded values `E3` and `F3` using the [`MAP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) function.*</sup>

> The [`MAP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) function returns an array formed by mapping each value in the array(s) to a new value by applying a [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) to create a new value.
> `=MAP(array1, lambda_or_array<#>)`

```
=MAP(E3:E10, F3:F10,
     LAMBDA(_val1,_val2,
            (LAMBDA(_c1,_c2,
                    COUNTIFS(_c1,_val1,_c2,_val2)
            )(A:A,B:B)
 )))
```

[image]

### LET Formula (#3)

---

<sup>*If you don't want to define the number of rows (lookup pairs) in your lookup array, you can adapt the [`LAMBDA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) formula above with the [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function.  This is useful if the lookup array is itself dynamically generated, or the formula is reused on other sheets with different sized arrays, or other reasons.*</sup>

> The [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function assigns names to calculation results. This allows storing intermediate calculations, values, or defining names inside a formula. These names only apply within the scope of the [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function. Similar to variables in programming, [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) is accomplished through Excel’s native formula syntax.
>
> To use the [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function in Excel, you define pairs of names and associated values, and a calculation that uses them all. You must define at least one name/value pair (a variable), and [`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) supports up to 126.

<sup>*[`LET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) allows filtering `E:F` and storing in `_valArr` the result which only includes rows with values <>"" and also excludes `E1:F2` which are title rows in this spreadsheet. The `_valArr` array is then split into two columns and stored in `_val1Col` and `_val2Col` respectively. These last are now used instead of `E3:E10` and `F3:F10` in the same [`MAP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) function used in the previous formula.*</sup>

```
=LET(
  _valCols, E:F,
  _valArr, FILTER(_valCols,(INDEX(_valCols,,1)<>"")*(ROW(_valCols)>2)),
  _val1Col, INDEX(_valArr,,1), _val2Col, INDEX(_valArr,,2),
  MAP(_val1Col, _val2Col,
      LAMBDA(_val1,_val2,
            (LAMBDA(_c1,_c2,
                    COUNTIFS(_c1,_val1,_c2,_val2))(A:A,B:B)))))
```

[image]